# Please explain to me that Loop is a data structure or not

Tags: loops

I am confuse about that loop is a data structure or not? please explain it to me. if it is not not a data structure, please explain why it is not. If it is, then explain why it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop is not a data structure. A loop is a programming construct that allows a program to do an action[s] repetitively as long as the conditions defined for the loop are met. An example is a for loop and a while loop. A data structure, on the other hand, is an organization of data that will allow efficient storage, access and manipulation. For example, an array or list is a data structure. A loop can be used to traverse an Array. A loop itself does not contain any data.

Answer (score 0):

A data structure contains some data. What data does a loop contain?

Answer (score 0):

A data structure usually contains other objects. A control structure alters the sequential flow of the code. Which is basically what a loop does. In simple words, a loop controls in which direction your code goes and not which objects your code uses.

Happy learning,
Rupak